# how to switch to a new buffer with ido without needing to confirm?

Tags: ido

**Q:** how do I switch to a new buffer with `ido` without needing to confirm?

I open up a lot of temporary buffers to do scratchpad work.  When `ido-switch-buffer` can't find a match for the buffer name I'm entering in the minibuffer (because, as per use case, it's a new one), it asks me to confirm that I really wanted this unknown buffer.  I'd rather not have that extra step (admittedly small) to break my concentration.

I presume there is a setting I'm missing, but how do I turn off the "confirm" query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer to this question with some additional digging, but I'll leave it up in case others have this question in the future.

The variable in question is `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer`.  It looks like the default is `after-completion`, but setting it to `nil` turns of the confirmation request.

The variable is relevant not just for `ido` and family, but also for a wider range of functions like `switch-to-buffer` and `find-file`.  Rather than change the default everywhere, we can  turn off confirmation for just this one functionwith a little bit of advice:

```
(defadvice ido-switch-buffer (around no-confirmation activate)
  (let ((confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Works fine, even with `flx-ido` and `ido-ubiquitous`.

Answer (score 3):

Set `ido-create-new-buffer` variable to `(quote always)`
 using customize, or by adding `(setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)` to your init file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work for this issue.  Even with `ido-create-new-buffer` set to `'always`, I still get the confirmation query.

Comment: Odd, it definitely fixed the problem for me; see also http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode for reference, and other ido trickeries.

Comment: That *is* odd, because the use-case described in the link you cited is pretty much exactly what I was going for.  Looking back at my init file, I'd actually tried that a while back and have a note-to-self that it didn't work.  One untested possibility is that something about `flx-ido` and/or `ido-ubiquitous`, both of which I use, is interfering.

Comment: Yeah, I use this approach as well. Must be some other aspect for your configuration in play here.

Comment: I spoke too soon.. Just trying with a clean 24.4 instance and see what @Dan reported. It turns out I had previously set `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer` to nil. If you do that there is a different confirmation prompt from ido, which you can avoid with `ido-create-new-buffer`.

Comment: Can confirm, initially was confused because `ido-create-new-buffer` seemed to do nothing. Only after setting `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer` to nil did the value of `ido-create-new-buffer` actually do anything.